# Quadratic Programming CPLEX

Tags: python, cplex, quadratic-programming

I am trying to implement a simple quadratic program using CPLEX's Python API. The sample file qpex1 provided with CPLEX discusses this. The problem, as mentioned in qpex.lp is

```
Maximize
 obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + [ - 33 x1 ^2 + 12 x1 * x2 - 22 x2 ^2 + 23 x2 * x3
 - 11 x3 ^2 ] / 2
Subject To
 c1: - x1 + x2 + x3 <= 20
 c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
Bounds
0 <= x1 <= 40
End
```

The problem, while being implemented in python, receives a matrix qmat which implements the quadratic portion of the objective function. The matrix is :

```
qmat = [[[0, 1], [-33.0, 6.0]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [6.0, -22.0, 11.5]],
        [[1, 2], [11.5, -11.0]]]

p.objective.set_quadratic(qmat)
```

Can someone explain the structure of this matrix? What are the parts in the data structure that is being used? What are the components and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First list is the set of indeces, the second list the set of the corresponding values, so the `qmat` matrix is:

```
-33   6   0
  6  -22  11.5
  0  11.5 -11
```

that results in:

```
         | -33   6   0    | x1
x1 x2 x3 |   6  -22  11.5 | x2 = - 33 x1 ^2 + 12 x1 * x2 - 22 x2 ^2 + 23 x2 * x3 - 11 x3 ^2
         |   0  11.5 -11  | x3
```